# Flash: Grant access to webcam programmatically / behind the scenes?

Tags: flash, webcam

We're building a kiosk app that will have a fairly wide deployment. The app is in Flash running in a browser and requires the use of the webcam. As it stands, each kiosk will show the usual Flash "do you want to allow the use of your camera/microphone" dialog, which I suppose a local admin could click through, choose "remember," etc.

Given that this is a kiosk app, where we have access to the machines themselves (or at least to people who do), is there a way to pre-seed the whitelist so the dialog does not appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run a local application (not Flash) that can read/write the file system, then you can find the settings and change them.  They're stored in a local shared object under the `macromedia.com` domain as well as the domain of the app to allow.

The exact location varies, but on my machine one example is here:

```
C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\#ungrounded.net\settings.sol
```

This is the settings file for a tutorial here:

http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/326194

(the swf is actually hosted on undergrounded.net).

Here's an SOL viewer:

http://www.buraks.com/asv/tools/sve.html

And more information on editing SOL and software here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object

Comment: Thank you, this puts me on the right track.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/soleditor/ is an open source SOL editor, trying it out now.

Comment: @Panzercrisis, yes, it can be done in VB.NET.  Look at the wikipedia article above as a starting point.  It lists several open source projects that read and write sol files.  Use those as a basis for doing what you need to do.